# How to pass arguments to tcl scripts when using tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I have two tcl scripts to which I want to pass arguments. The first gets a number and gives its factorial, the second gets two numbers and performs some conditionals and outputs accordingly. I am using tclsh on Cygwin. I cannot pass arguments to the script as I run the script in this way:
`$ tclsh fact.tcl`
which gives the error that I have not provided proper number of arguments for the script.
To pass the argument, I tried the following, but ended up receiving the error "extra characters after close-brace":
`tclsh fact.tcl 5`
The tcl code for factorial is:

```
if {$argc !=1} {
    puts stderr "Error! ns called with wrong number of arguments! ($argc)"
    exit 1
} else {
    set f [lindex $argv 0]
}


proc Factorial {x} {
for {set result 1} {$x>1}{set x [expr $x - 1]}{
    set result [expr $result * $x]
}
return $result
}
set res [Factorial $f]
puts "Factorial of $f is $res"
```

And the tcl code for conditionals (second script) is as follows:

```
if {$argc!=2} {
    puts "Error! incorrect parameter count ($argc)"
    exit 1
}
set a [lindex $argv 0]
set b [lindex $argv 1]


if {fmod($a, 2) ==0} {
    if {fmod($b,2) ==0} {
        if {$a<$b}
        puts "a and b even; pow=[expr pow($a,$b)]"
        else 
        puts "a and b even. pow=[expr pow($b,$a)]"
    }
    else {
        if{$a>=$b}
            puts [expr $a-$b]
        else 
            puts [expr $b-$a]

    }
}
else if {fmod($a,2)==1} {
    if {fmod($b,2)==1} {
        if {$a<$b}
        puts "a and b even; pow=[expr pow($a,$b)]"
        else 
        puts "a and b even. pow=[expr pow($b,$a)]"
    }
    else {
        if{$a>=$b}
            puts [expr $a-$b]
        else 
            puts [expr $b-$a]

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to leave a space in `for` loop condition.

Comment: @Dinesh, both scripts seem to compile perfectly before adding parameters.

Comment: @JasonStack: Tcl doesn't compile until the code is executed for the first time. You won't get any errors until you add those arguments.

Comment: There's no `else` command in (standard) Tcl. Your code will not work until you get your brace-habits right.